# Abrir una nueva vista al precionar una un item de una tabla en Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Tengo un problema con una tabla creada en Xcode8 y Swift 3, mi tabla se genera por código quiero decir que todo el contenido de la tabla se carga desde arreglos en su clase y con los metodos "numberOfSections" y "numberOfRowsInSection", genero mi tabla cuando se ejecuta la aplicación, pero ahora mi duda es: como puedo programar el segue para que dependiendo de la celda seleccionada me abra una nueva vista, asi tengo mi Main. storyboard:

Tengo mi Table View Controller y los segues que tengo ahí es para que al presionar la celda 0 me envié a Caja de ahorro y si presiono la celda 1 me envié a otra vista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código completo de la clase donde esta mi tabla es este:

```
//
//  ControlTablaPrincipalTableViewController.swift
//  Seccion 15
//
//  Created by Barbatos on 7/10/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Seccion 15. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ControlTablaPrincipalTableViewController:UITableViewController {

    var titulos : [String] = ["Caja de ahorro","Blog de la Seccion 15","Iniciar Sesion","Galeria de eventos","Convenios", "Ubicacion", "Contactanos"]

    var imagenes : [UIImage] = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "caja"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "blog"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "sesion"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "galeria"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "convenio"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ubicacion"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "contacto")]

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.dataSource = self

        self.tableView.delegate = self

    }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections

        return 1

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

        return titulos.count

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

        cell?.imageView!.image = imagenes[indexPath.row]

        cell?.textLabel?.text = titulos[indexPath.row]

        return cell!

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Celda seleccionada", message: "Se selecciono la celda \(indexPath.row)",preferredStyle: .alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(okAction)

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        if(indexPath.row == 0){

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Para ir de un viewController a otro, en didSelectRowAtIndexPath debes hacer el perform del Segue:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.indexPath = indexPath
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil)
}
```

2- Si quieres pasar algun dato del viewcontroller origen al segundo viewcontroller debes sobreescibri el prepare for Segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue"{
        let vc = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        guard let index = indexPath else{return}
        vc.indexPath = index
    }
}
```

En este ejemplo estoy pasando el indexPath de la tabla que seleccione al segundo ViewController.

En lo personal te recomendaria instanciar el Storyboard y hacer un present o un push si tienes un navigation controller:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Second") as! SecondViewController
        controller.indexPath = indexPath
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
//        Si tienes un navigation controller usa esta line
//        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Si, muchas gracias tienes razon, gracias por tu respuesta funciono a la perfeccion